# Choosing a supply voltage for an instrumentation amplifier

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I am using a Wheatstone bridge to measure a resistance and an instrumentation amplifier to amplify the signal. Specifically, I am using the [INA121](https://docs.rs-online.com/57f8/A700000006811975.pdf). According to the amplifier datasheet, the input voltage can be in the range of ±2.5V and ±15V. In addition, it says that

> Typical performance curves, “Input Common-Mode Range vs Output Voltage” show the range of linear operation for ±15V, ±5V, and ±2.5V supplies.

Therefore, my choice would be one of those voltages. However, which one should I choose? Does a high voltage offer advantages over a low voltage (or vice-versa) in instrumentation amplifiers?

Comment: The common mode voltage has to fall within the rails of the power supply - specifically [(V+) - 1.2] to [(V-) + 2.1] typ. So higher voltage will give you more headroom. Also, your output voltage has to fall within the power supply rails - more specifically, [(V+) - 0.9] to [(V-) + 0.15].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With instrumentation amplifiers, in addition to input voltage range and output voltage range you would look it for an op-amp, you also have to pay attention to the "Diamond" diagrams to ensure you have high enough supply voltages that internal nodes don't saturate.

From your datasheet link:

[image]

Analog Devices has an excellent "[Diamond Plot Tool](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/studentzone/studentzone-september-2017.html)" which can simplify this analysis with their products, however the part design you have is owned by TI (née Burr-Brown).